# Cron is not logging stderr in /var/mail/user

Tags: linux, cron, mailx

I have this user who have a lot of cron jobs and I expected it to log stderr in its /var/mail/user. Sample below cron entry is working as expected in a different server.

```
* 30 * * * * /usr/local/bin/scripts/test.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
```

I've compared postfix/main.cf on both servers and cannot find anything different. Is there something else I need to check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an explicit redirection in the cron command: `> /dev/null 2>&1`. It means both stdout and stderr are thrown away. There's no basis to expect any mail then. To keep stderr, leave just this redirection at the end: `>/dev/null`.

Comment: Thank you so much this have been very helpful. I overlooked those redirections when comparing from another working system.